# Java NIO - attaching to telnet/bash/etc. command line utilities

Tags: java, timeout, nio, stdio

Is it possible to use Java NIO to connect to external programs' stdio/stdin? I need intput/output read/write operations with timeouts.

Please quote any examples if you know some.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible at all unless you started the process. If you did, you can get streams from it, and convert those streams to channels and then use blocking-mode NIO operations.

But I don't know why you would want to use NIO for this.